# converting bytes to kB and MB pending of the cell data in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question:
Lets say i have got 2 cells (A1 and A2). on A1 i have a value of 16000000 and on cell A2 a value of 230000.
both values are in bytes. what i need is to be able to convert them to MB and kB respectively with VBA code.

i can start dividing A1/1024/1024 and A2/1024 but what i would like to know is how do i make the vba code diferentiate between the 2 values and then convert them to their respective category.
i could convert both of them to MB by dividing by 1024 but that would leave me with cell A2 with a value of 0.23MB.
i am not asking for code to be written for me, just for an explanation on how to do this if possible.

Comment: `=IF(A1/1024/1024>1,ROUND(A1/1024/1024,2) & " MB",IF(A1/1024>1,ROUND(A1/1024,2) & " kB",A1 & " B"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can handle using 10³ (aka *1,000*) as a Kb instead of 2¹⁰ (aka *1,024*) and 10⁶ (aka *1,000,000*) as a Mb instead of 2²⁰ (aka *1,048,576*) then a [Custom Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) will preserve the raw underlying value while displaying the unit of size.

```
range("B2:B99").NumberFormat = "[Color10][>999999]0,, \M\b;[Color13][>999]0, K\b;[Color3]0 \B;"
```

I have also added blue for Mb, green for Kb and red for B.

[image: MB_KB_B]